# Quickfixj Persist Messages

Tags: java, quickfix

I have an acceptor application which sends Market Data to the user. The problem is that even though we have set `PersistMessages = N` for the sessions we can see that messages are persisted . As per the quickfixj help doc if we set `PersistMessages = N` then

> If set to N, no messages will be persisted. This will force QuickFIX
>   to always send GapFills instead of resending messages. Use this if you
>   know you never want to resend a message. Useful for market data
>   streams.

Any help on this issue is appreciated

Thank in advance 
Arvind

Comment: A message log excerpt (created with a FileLogFactory) would be helpful.  Can you edit your question to include 10-20 messages that include and are before/after your resending?

Comment: wondering how you solved it - did you simply comment out the filestorepath in combination with PersistMessages=N?

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste your config file or something which would be useful? 
The messages you see in your log file could possibly be admin messages. 
As far as I know, even if you set PersistMessages = N, admin messages will be there in the file

Comment: I have pasted below [DEFAULT] ConnectionType=acceptor SocketAcceptPort=8085 StartTime=00:00:00 EndTime=00:00:00 MillisecondsInTimeStamp=Y CheckLatency=N PersistMessages=N ResetOnLogon=Y ResetOnLogout=Y ResetOnDisconnect=Y RefreshOnLogon=N [SESSION]  HeartBtInt=30 BeginString=FIX.4.2 SenderCompID=XXXXXX TargetCompID=XXXXXx UseDataDictionary=N DataDictionary=yourpath/FIX42.xml FileLogPath=yourpath/store/ FileStorePath=yourpath/store/ –

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with your configuration file. In any case, if you are seeing persisted messages, you must be using a MessageStore that supports persistence. You can also define an empty MessageStore implementation that doesn't store anything and this will have the same effect as the setting (gap fills instead of resent messages). However, using the setting is easier and is the preferred method.

Comment: I am a bit confused with the cfg file ie where whould i need to add "PersistMessages = N" is it at [DEFAULT] level or session level . Does it make a difference ?        [DEFAULT]

ConnectionType=acceptor
SocketAcceptPort=8085
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
MillisecondsInTimeStamp=Y
CheckLatency=N
PersistMessages=N
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
RefreshOnLogon=N

[SESSION]  

HeartBtInt=30
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SenderCompID=XXXXXX
TargetCompID=XXXXXx
UseDataDictionary=N
DataDictionary=yourpath/FIX42.xml
FileLogPath=yourpath/store/
FileStorePath=yourpath/store/